# Request for c&p of deleted answer and comments

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I am not sure what caused the deletion of (what I believe was) [Space left on Linux RAM/TMP,FS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90717/space-left-on-linux-ram-tmp-fs/90789#90789), but there was a link in there that now seems to be dead, presuming I remember it correctly.

Any chance of a 10k'r copying and pasting the answer and comments here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I deleted my answer since a better one was posted and it did not add anything useful to the debate. I have now undeleted it and it should be accessible to you again. I guess you're looking for the parted magic isos.

Comment: Thanks. "I guess you're looking for the parted magic isos." - Yes, they seem to have disappeared, however.